# How to keep everything but the first token with bash pipe?

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have this:

```
echo "   word1  word2 word3" | awk '{print $1;}' # Prints "word1"
```

I want to remove everything before the beginning of the second token, so I want to keep `word2 word3`..what I could do is just remove the first token and then trim the remainder, but I don't know how to keep everything but the first token.

Comment: `echo "   word1  word2 word3" | rev | awk 'NF--' | rev` ;)

Comment: Is the pattern after the first token always known? i.e. in your case `word2`? and _why_ do you need to use a pipe? There are tons of ways to manipulate strings using linux tools

Comment: it doesn't have to be a pipe

Comment: @Cyrus doesn't quite work, I get all 3 tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  echo "   word1  word2      word3" | read skip rest
```

Will store just *word2     word3* on `rest`. See the *read* command in the bash man page.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me: `echo "   word1  word2      word3" | read skip rest | cat`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to pipe it into `cat`. As I said, the two words are **stored** in `rest`. Just do a `echo $rest`.

Comment: A variable stored in a command from a pipeline won't be available after the pipe exits. do `read skip rest <<<"   word1  word2      word3"`

Comment: @Inian: This is not a problem here, because the `read` is executed in the current bash process, where it sets the variables `skip`and `rest`. While `read` reads from the pipe, there are no variables set in a subprocess here (which indeed woul not be available in the main process).

Comment: @AlexanderMills : Correct. If you really want to pipe it into somewhere else. Since it is just a simple string, it would perhaps make more sense to pass it as a parameter instead of a pipe, but of course this depends on what the receiving side expects.

Comment: just for other user's sake, is skipping 2 tokens as easy as skipping one token using `read`?

Comment: also, is there a way to store the skipped token? I guess it's stored in $skip isn't it...that's pretty cool

Comment: just extend my suggestion to more than one token: `echo a  b c  d| read skip AleanderMillsIgnoresThe2ndTokenToo rest`

Comment: @user1934428: Not sure what you mean what is the problem here. You can't do `echo "   word1  word2      word3" | read skip rest` and then `echo` out the variables. They just won't be available

Comment: @AlexanderMills : But the skipped token *is* stored! It's in `skip`. You did read the bash man-page, as I suggested, didn't you? Then you know how the command works.

Comment: nah I figured it out, I like this a lot

Comment: @Inian : My mistake.  When I suggested this, i was using Zsh for testing, which is the shell I'm normally using. But the OP uses bash. In Zsh it works, in bash it does not. I didn't expect bash and Zsh to be different in *this* respect. Sorry, AlexanderMills.

Comment: @user1934428: It also works with bash >=4.2, but it's more cumbersome: `set +m; shopt -s lastpipe; echo a b c d | read skip rest; echo "$rest"`

Answer (score 0):

awk has for: `echo "   word1  word2 word3" | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;++i)print $i}'`

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but this would destroy the spacing between the words.The OP wanted to keep *everything* after the first token, which I understood that this includes the number of spaces between the token.

Comment: There is probably something simpler, If you need to keep the spacing you can use `sed 's/^[ \t]*//'` to trim the leading spaces and `cut -d ' ' -f 2-` to take everything after the first space, something like: `echo "   word1  word2 word3" |sed 's/^[ \t]*//'  | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | sed 's/^[ \t]*//'` or if you need to trim the leading space: `echo "   word1  word2 word3   w4 w5 " |sed 's/^[ \t]*//'  | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | sed 's/^[ \t]*//'`